# v1.0 - Notary mismatch

Tags: corda

In one test, I got
Input state requires notary "C=GB,L=London,O=Mock Company 1" which does not match the transaction notary "C=GB,L=London,O=Mock Company 1,CN=corda.notary.validating".

They should be the same one.  The only difference is CN which is optional.

How can I avoid the error?

\Sean

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the notary? Each node has a main identity, as well as an optional notary identity. Is it possible that you're retrieving the former, rather than the latter?

To get the notary, you should be using `NetworkMapCache.getNotary`, which takes a CordaX500Name and only searches for notary identities with this name.